# Need to prove $uD\psi=\frac{n}{2} \text{grad}(u)\cdot\psi$

Tags: dirac-operator, spinor

I'm reading Thomas Friedrich's article "[On the conformal relation between twistors and Killing spinors](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/701462)" and I'm stuck in a part of the proof of proposition 3 (page 64), which states:

**Proposition 3** *Let $\psi\neq 0$ be a twistor spinor, $u=\langle\psi,\,\psi\rangle$ (where $\langle,\rangle$ is the hermitian inner product induced in the spinors space). Denote by $\gamma:[0,\,T]\longrightarrow M^n$ a geodesic joining of two zero points of $\psi$ (i.e. $\psi(\gamma(0))=0=\psi(\gamma(T))$ , then:

$
\begin{align}
a) &\text{Ric}(\dot{\gamma}) \hspace{0.2cm}\text{ is parallel to }\hspace{0.1cm}\dot{\gamma}\\
\end{align}$

$ b) \text{grad}(u) \hspace{0.2cm}\text{ is parallel to }\hspace{0.1cm}\dot{\gamma}$

$ c) \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{n^2}{2}g(S(\dot{\gamma}),\dot{\gamma})\frac{du}{dt}$

$ d) uv=\frac{n^2}{4}\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)^2$

So, in a part Friedrich says: "Since $\psi$ is a twistor spinor vanishing at some point, we have $$u D\psi=\frac{n}{2}\text{grad}(u)\cdot\psi,$$
where $D$ is the Dirac's operator."

I'm struggling figuring out how to pass from the condition that $\psi$ is a twistor spinor (which means $\nabla_X\psi+\frac{1}{n}X\cdot D\psi=0$, for all $X\in\Gamma(M^n)$, to previos equation.

I don't know if it is important the next definitions in order to understand what is happening but for whatever:

$v=\langle D\psi,D\psi\rangle$

$S(X)=\frac{nR}{4(n-1)(n-2)} X-\frac{n}{2(n-2)}\text{Ric}(X)$, where $Ric$ is the linear Ricci operator.

$g(,)$ is the Riemannian metric of $M$

I'm guessing that I need to construc a relation whose derivative respect $t$ vanish so I can  take the condition "$\psi$ is zero in some point" and make the whole thing zero, but I can't figure out which.

I am thankful for any kind of help